# Decimal values in SQL for dividing results

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

In SQL, I have `col1` and `col2`. Both are integers.

I want to do like:

```
select col1/col2 from tbl1
```

I get the result `1` where `col1=3` and `col2=2`

The result I want is `1.1`

I put `round(col1/col2,2)`. The result is still 1.

I put `decimal(col1/col2,2)`. The decimal is not built in function.

How can I do exactly to get 1.1?

Comment: is it 3 divided by 2 equal 1.5 ?

Comment: What kind of rounding gives you 3/2 = 1.1?

Comment: @Blorgbeard: He might have automatically converted it to binary. :)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You will need to cast or convert the values to decimal before division. Take a look at this
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054.aspx

For example

```
DECLARE @num1 int = 3 DECLARE @num2 int = 2

SELECT @num1/@num2

SELECT @num1/CONVERT(decimal(4,2), @num2)
```

The first SELECT will result in what you're seeing while the second SELECT will have the correct answer `1.500000`

Answer (score 161):

Just another approach:

```
SELECT col1 * 1.0 / col2 FROM tbl1
```

Multiplying by 1.0 turns an integer into a <s>float</s> [numeric(13,1)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0b924/1) and so works like a typecast, but most probably it is slower than that.

A slightly shorter variation suggested by [Aleksandr Fedorenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1085940/aleksandr-fedorenko) in a comment:

```
SELECT col1 * 1. / col2 FROM tbl1
```

The effect would be basically the same. The only difference is that the multiplication result in this case would be [numeric(12,0)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0b924/2).

Principal advantage: less wordy than other approaches.

Comment: Is 1. just short form for 1.0?

Comment: @Jackson: Technically, [not quite](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0b924/5), but in the broader sense that both are interpreted as numeric, yes, you could say so.

Answer (score 19):

`SELECT CAST (col1 as float) / col2 FROM tbl1`

One cast should work. ("Less is more.")

From [Books Online](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175009.aspx):

> Returns the data type of the argument with the higher precedence. For more information about data type precedence, see [Data Type Precedence (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx).
>
> If an integer *dividend* is divided by an integer *divisor*, the result is an integer that has any fractional part of the result truncated

Answer (score 7):

```
CAST( ROUND(columnA *1.00 / columnB, 2) AS FLOAT)
```

Comment: tanx alot <br>
get percentage from this solution must result * 100 :)

Answer (score 3):

There may be other ways to get your desired result.

```
Declare @a int
Declare @b int
SET @a = 3
SET @b=2
SELECT cast((cast(@a as float)/ cast(@b as float)) as float)
```

Answer (score 1):

just convert denominator to decimal before division e.g

`select  col1 / CONVERT(decimal(4,2), col2)  from  tbl1`

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, decimal values can be used for dividing results by specifying decimal literals or using decimal columns in the division operation. Here's an example:

Let's say you have a table called "Sales" with two columns: "Revenue" and "Expenses." You want to calculate the profit margin, which is the ratio of revenue to expenses.

```
SELECT Revenue / Expenses AS ProfitMargin FROM Sales;
```

In this example, assuming both "Revenue" and "Expenses" columns are decimal values, the division operation will automatically handle decimal calculations and return the result as a decimal value.

If you want to divide by a decimal literal, you can explicitly specify it in the query:

```
SELECT Revenue / 100.0 AS Percentage FROM Sales;
```

Here, we're dividing the "Revenue" column by 100.0, which is a decimal literal. The result will be a decimal value representing the percentage.

Remember, when performing division in SQL, ensure that the denominator is not zero to avoid potential errors.