# MSSQL - Getting decimals in a division

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm using MSSQL 2014 and I'd like to know if there is a better way to display 2 decimals in a simple division like 10/3.

```
SELECT 10/3 -- returns 3
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), 10/3) -- RETURNS 3
SELECT CAST(10/3 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) -- RETURNS 3
```

The only way I found to make it work is by casting the divisor as float:

```
SELECT 10/CAST(3 AS FLOAT) -- returns 3.333333...
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), 10/CAST(3 AS FLOAT)) -- RETURNS 3.33
SELECT CAST(10/CAST(3 AS FLOAT) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) -- RETURNS 3.33
```

Are these two last options the best approach available?. Is it possible to do this without any cast/conversion?

Comment: SELECT 10 * 1.0 / 3 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834973/decimal-values-in-sql-for-dividing-results

Comment: SELECT CAST(ROUND(10/3.0,2) as DECIMAL(10,2)) ? dont see any significant difference though

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, to truncate you have to specify that you only want two digits.  If it were me I'd do:

```
SELECT cast(10/3.0 as decimal(10,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I get a float if I do,

```
select 10/3.0
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11719098/28045

Answer (score 0):

Division of one integer by another will result in an integer. Either cast the numbers or use variables of float or decimal type having values of 10 and 3.

Comment: For a quick workaround:

` 
SELECT var1*1.0/var2*1.0 
FROM ...
`