# Why does SQL Server lose values making a division

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2012.

I have the following operation:

```
select 1/12
```

Why does it result in zero?

I expect 0.08333333

Regards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decimal values in SQL for dividing results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834973/decimal-values-in-sql-for-dividing-results)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integer division in sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443672/integer-division-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 2):

You're implicitly asking for an integer result, because both "1" and "12" are integers.  All you have to do is to change one (or both) of them to a decimal to get what you want.

```
SELECT 1.0/12
```