# Convert a count in which 'partition by' is used to percentage with decimal places in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, percentage, division, partition

I would like to convert a `COUNT` which includes `PARTITION BY` in SQL Server.  Desired output would be percentage to 2 decimal places with '%' symbol included (`78.48%` instead of `78`, for example).

Here is what I have:

```
(((100 * COUNT(STC_GRADE)) / SUM(COUNT(STC_GRADE)) OVER (PARTITION BY STC_COURSE_NAME 
                                                         ORDER BY STC_COURSE_NAME))) AS Percentage
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Integer division always returns an integer result. Convert one of your values to a decimal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decimal values in SQL for dividing results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834973/decimal-values-in-sql-for-dividing-results)

Comment: Unfortunately I am unsure how to 'write' it out with the OVER (PARTITION BY....) part in my query.

Comment: Just change 100 to 100.00 :)

Comment: Thank you so much Dale!  That will get me by for right now!