# Calculate Percentage in Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to add a percentage column to my table but my results are funky with the sql below:

```
update code_data
set code_red_percent = case when red_code_count = 0 then 0
                            else (red_code_count / total_code_count) * 100
                       end
```

It seems to be populating by percent column with 100 any time that the total_code_count and red_code_count match, but any time that the numbers are different it updates the percent column to a 0. What am I missing here?

Comment: Actually sample data, desired results and actual results would help. But I assume this is the issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834973/decimal-values-in-sql-for-dividing-results

Comment: Avoid data inconsistency, use a _computed column_.

Comment: First I think your divide is backwards.  You need total/red.  Also you are doing divide on int it looks like you need to cast them as decimal to get a decimal output or your divide will be a whole number and it will be 0 (if less than 50) or 1 if more than 50 because it would round off.

Comment: @Brad, it's red/total to get red percentage. E.g 4 red out of 8: 4 / 8 * 100 will give you 50%.

Comment: Is `code_red_percent` an `INT`?  If yes, then there is your answer.

Comment: Have you tried `(CAST(red_code_count AS FLOAT) / total_code_count) * 100`?

Comment: First question to ask: why are you storing a calculated value in your table?  [Please make sure you understand the implications of doing so](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/202758/bad-practice-to-store-calculated-data-in-database) because in many cases, it should be avoided.

Comment: @Eric certainly not `FLOAT` - that datatype should never be used unless the data is truly scientific data.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are hitting integer division; multiply *first*:

```
update code_data set
  code_red_percent =
    case 
      when red_code_count = 0 then 0
      else 100 * red_code_count / total_code_count
    end
```

Comment: Surely we can flag this as a duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (code_red_count INT, total_code_count INT, code_red_percent AS (CAST(code_red_count AS DECIMAL(10,2))/CAST(total_code_count AS DECIMAL(10,2))), code_red_percent_upd DECIMAL(10,2));
INSERT INTO @Table (code_red_count, total_code_count) VALUES
(1, 10), (2, 10), (3, 10), (50,10);

SELECT *, code_red_count/total_code_count AS code_red_percent_int, CAST(code_red_count AS DECIMAL(10,2))/CAST(total_code_count AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS code_red_percent_dec
  FROM @Table;

UPDATE @Table
  SET code_red_percent_upd = CAST(code_red_count AS DECIMAL(10,2))/CAST(total_code_count AS DECIMAL(10,2));

SELECT *
  FROM @Table;
```

First, we create a table and populate it with some example data (it's helpful if you provide this when asking a question).

The first `SELECT` shows two calculations. The first using `INT` values and the second `DECIMAL` values. You can see the `INT` values are returned as a rounded  `INT`. The `DECIMAL` values return the expected result.

We can use the same method to perform the `UPDATE` if that's what you really want.

In the initial table definition I also included another column without a data type, instead providing a definition for the calculation required to get the value. This is pretty much the same as the calculation used in the select, except it's automatically handled by the engine, and will always be up to date if the values it's derived from ever change. This is a computed column: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver16

| code_red_count | total_code_count | code_red_percent | code_red_percent_upd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 0.1000000000000 | 0.10 |
| 2 | 10 | 0.2000000000000 | 0.20 |
| 3 | 10 | 0.3000000000000 | 0.30 |
| 50 | 10 | 5.0000000000000 | 5.00 |

Comment: Surely we can flag this as a duplicate?

Comment: Maybe? The question does kind of beg to have computed columns discussed too, though?